# VueJS - v-if and v-show don't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this structure inside Vue DIV:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="well chart-container">
                    <div id="chart" v-if="chartShown"></div>
                    <h1 v-if="textShown">{{staticPropertyValue}}</h1>
                </div>            
            </div>
```

In my application I'd like to be able to display chart div OR h1 tag. Here's a part of my javaScript:

```
app.textShown = false;
app.chartShown = true;

if (data.length == 0) {
    MG.data_graphic({
        title: "Missing Data",
        description: "",
        error: 'No data',
        chart_type: 'missing-data',
        missing_text: 'There is no data',
        target: '#chart',
        full_width: true,
        height: 600
    });

    return;
};

if (data.length == 1) {
    app.staticPropertyValue = data[0].value;
    app.chartShown = false;
    app.textShown = true;
    return;
}

console.log('DRAWING GRAPH');
console.log(document.getElementById('chart'));
 MG.data_graphic({
    title: "Fetched data",
    description: "",
    data: data,
    full_width: true,
    height: 600,
    target: '#chart',
    x_accessor: 'time',
    y_accessor: 'value'
});
```

So, depending on data.length property, the chart is shown or h1 tag is shown. The problem appears, when I first time call above code and display h1 tag (because data.length == 1) and then next time I call it with date.length > 1 (chart should appear). I get error:

> The specified target element "#chart" could not be found in the page.
>   The chart will not be rendered.

It is from the library that I'm using for drawing charts - metricsgraphics.js.
So I console logged the result of

```
document.getElementById('chart')
```

and it was *null*. So it means that although i switch chartShown to true, it's not done fast enough. How can I fix this?

I also tried using v-show instead of v-if - didn't work well - I had some errors about the width of some elements being NaN.

Comment: Are you sure that your script is after the DOM is? Try adding defer to your script tag, or moving it to the bottom of your body.

Comment: Showing your component's code would be helpful.

Comment: @Cobaltway I have a script in seperate file - the part I'm showing is a function that is fired when some event happens - it happens when user chooses something from a dropdown.

Comment: @Potray - what component code?

Answer (score 0):

You should run this piece of code in the `mounted()` callback of your component.

To me, it looks like you're running it when the script has finished loading, which is not necessarily when the DOM is fully built and definitely not when Vue has finished rendering its components.

Working with `v-if` while using an external library is not a good idea anyway, you're much better off initializing your view in the `mounted()` callback and then watching your `chartShown` variable like so:

```
{
  ...,
  watch: {
    chartShown(nv) {
      if (nv) {
        // setup chart
      } else {
        // remove chart
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: But my code is being fired many times during runtime. During the load stage it's not fired at all. When user chooses something from the dropdown - then it's called - DOM is loaded already in that moment

Comment: We're going to need the callbacks in which you fire this code then.

Comment: It's called when dropdown selection changes - I did @change="my function" and also added this function in 'methods' section of Vue